# Client server application with notifications using NetMQ

Tags: c#, architecture, zeromq, software-design, netmq

I need to create client-server applications in local network with such functionality:

1. single server (data access and so on ...)
2. multi clients (ordinary 3-5, up to 20)
3. each client must authorize on server (need to check what rights it has)
4. client send request to server (ordinary less than 1 Kb, up to 3-5 Kb) and get responses (ordinary 30-100 Kb, some times it can be a big amount of data, up to 1-2 Mb)
5. after some queries from client(s) server notifies all clients and send them new and updated data (so server must know how much clients are connected)
6. if network connection dies, client must reconnect

I think NetMQ with Protobuf will be enough for my purposes. I look at documents and see, that the most suitable pattern for my task is http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Service-Oriented-Reliable-Queuing-Majordomo-Pattern when each client is a worker and server worker is a client at same time.

I think this solution too is complicated? 
Are there simpler ways to solve such problem (simpler pattern or maybe something based on WCF)?

Comment: I think using ZeroMQ for such task is an overkill, because you have such smal number of clients and data. I would better use web sockets to maintain persistent connection from client to server.

Comment: I love ZeroMQ and have used it for less! It may be a bit tricky to get started multithreading with it, but other than that it was a cinch to learn.